# Android Screen orientation landscape error?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I'm new to android and making an app in which there is layout design for both portrait and landscape mode. The app is running fine in both screen orientation except for one activity. The activity is working fine in portrait mode when i go from one activity to another, but crashes in landscape mode. I tried to solve this in different ways through Google search but didn't succeed. Please someone help me. Thanks

Comment: Did you use different xml for landscape and portrait mode?

Comment: You should post both portrait and landscape xml files of crashing activity. Probably you might be missing something in the landscape activity.

Comment: app is running in portrait mode but not in landscape mode

Comment: Add logcat and related code for that activity

Answer (score 0):

Use  this `android:configChanges="orientation"` inside your activity tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` hope this will help

Comment: This is not an answer. Please check the question again.

Answer (score 0):

Make two different resource folders in res folder like below:

1) layout --> put your main.xml

2) layout-land --> put your same main.xml in here too.

Note: in both res folders the name of layouts must be same.

Edit: well android handles orientation change automatically after above mentioned

procedure.. but if you want to handle it manually then here is the code to handle..

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) 
{
  Do something in Portrait
} 
else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
{
  Do something in Landscape
}
}
```

Add this below line in your manifest to the activity you want to handle orientation:

android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"

Answer (score 0):

Use this in Manifest.

> `<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape"   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:name="VncCanvasActivity">`

This line specifies the screenOrientation as landscape, but author goes further in overriding any screen orientation changes with configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

Comment: It seems that OP wants it to work on both portrait and landscape mode.

Comment: @17Coder : you haven't understand the question

Comment: @17Coder : if u add `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` this attribute to your activity in `manifest` the activity will always open in `landscape` mode you can't open it in `potrait` mode. Thats the reason

Comment: public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);                
  
}            we can call this method @kaushik

Comment: @zohaib  please post here full problem .??